# Dynamics AX 2009 - Duplicate IDs

Tags: object, axapta

We are in the process of merging projects from different AX Servers into source control on the same AX server.  However, a few object IDs are common between projects, so Dynamics throws an error when synchronizing:

```
e.g.  "BaseEnum ABC_123 can not be imported because XYZ_546 already has ID 30001"
```

What is the best/correct way to change IDs so there are no longer duplicates?

Is it as simple as modifying the xpo files in Source Safe to correct the duplicate IDs, or will that break other things?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the checkbox "Import with ID values" in Import dialog checked?  Try to uncheck it.

Comment: Exported, deleted from VSS, then reimported offending items without the IDs.  That worked.